# Prevent svg border gradient color

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I notice that svg adds some gradient borders in very tiny pixels around elements. Here's the jsfiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/XrkRT/

```
<rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="398"
      fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" />

<g stroke="green" >
  <line x1="100" y1="300" x2="300" y2="300"
          stroke-width="20" fill="none" />
</g>
```

How do I draw solid color line and rect. It's hard to see with normal zoom. I take a screenshot and zoom it in pixlr.com. Here's the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's antialiasing. You can turn it off with [shape-rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty)="crispEdges" but be aware that any diagonal lines will look rougher.

Comment: Why not include what it actually says? :) "Indicates that the user agent shall attempt to emphasize the contrast between clean edges of artwork over rendering speed and geometric precision. To achieve crisp edges, the user agent might turn off anti-aliasing for all lines and curves or possibly just for straight lines which are close to vertical or horizontal. Also, the user agent might adjust line positions and line widths to align edges with device pixels."